# How can I make a board out of a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a word puzzle game in python. The first hurdle I am encountering is that I can't quite make a board out of a list. My working code is below:

```
def get_words(n,words):
    global given
    count=1
    final=[given]
    while n!=count:
        count=count+1
        words=input('Enter a word:')
        final.append(words)
    return final

def sort_words(sorted_words):
    global sorted_
    bank={}
    x=sorted_words
    x.sort()
    W2=1
    print('Sorted words:')
    for y in x:
        print(y)
    for z in sorted_:
        bank.update({W2:z})
        W2=W2+1
    print(bank)

def populate_board(RxC,letter):
    global letters
    count=1
    final=[letters]
    while RxC!=count:
        letter=input('Enter row:')
        count=count+1
        final.append(letter)
    print(final)
    return final

def print_board(a,row):
    b=[]
    for y in a:
           b.append(y.upper())
    print(b)
    print(b.join('\n'))
    return board


num=int(input('Enter desired number of words:'))   
given=input('Enter a word:')
sorted_=get_words(num,given)

sort_words(sorted_)

m=int(input('Enter number of rows and column:'))
letters=str(input('Enter row:'))
board=populate_board(m,letters)

board2=print_board(board,letters)
```

All I get from these is a 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'', I really need help on how I can fix these.The function that supposedly prints the board is:

```
 def print_board(a,row):
        b=[]
        for y in a:
               b.append(y.upper())
        print(b)
        print(b.join('\n'))
        return board
```

I am also open for any suggestions that could make my code more efficient and what would be the best course of action on how to find the location and direction of the word. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Replace `b.join('\n')` with `'\n'.join(b)`. In Python, it's `string.join(iterable)`, not `iterable.join(string)`. Also, what is `board` in `return board`?

Comment: Hi MrGeek! Thanks for the correction! The board variable was supposed to be board=print(b.join('\n')). It seems I forgot to put it in there. I placed a return function there so I would be able to scan 'board' for the word. Is my reasoning good here? Because I am starting to worry on how I would be able to find a certain word in the board. I hope that the solution would produce a (col,row)-direction format.

Comment: `print(...)` returns `None`, so `board = print(...); return board` will make your function return `None`, instead, I think you should just `return b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_board(a,row):
    b=[]
    for y in a:
           b.append(y.upper())
    print(b)
    print('\n'.join(b))
    return board
```